# Should Getters/Setters contain Other Methods and Code, besides Get/Set?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Is it good practice to have methods, and other code within a getter/setter in Angular? Currently have teammates conducting following, wondering if it breaks any software principles.

```
public get customerSaleInput() {
    return this._customerSaleInput;
  }
public set customerSaleInput(val) {
    this._customerSaleInput = val;
    this.runCode();
    this.doExtraStuffetc();
}
```

Concern is having other code such as runCode, doExtraStuff, etc.

Comment: Don't have enough context in what each of those function do. This is more of a opinion based question. While it does probably make sense to have `ApplyCustomerDataInput()` but I don't see having `FindOrderTotal()` fit in that case. In my opinion that would be a method itself `GetOrderTotal()` or something along the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on each person preference. But to me, it break the Single Responsibility principle. In your example, the setter should do only 1 thing which is setting _customerSalesInput. Then the problem is how to keep other data up-to-date (I assume that you want to keep _orderTotal up-to-date with _customerSaleInput). Then you can create a method reCalculateTotal() and invoke the method whenever you need it.

Another problem may come up, what if you don't want to remember invoke that method before using the _orderTotal. Then the better way is to use a watch.

Comment: accepted answer and gave points, feel free to thumbs up question also